# Angular JS paging with Response from REST API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, rest

I am calling an REST API from Angular JS. I would like to know whats the best way of dispalying results on angular side . Get Full response from Spring Rest service and then implement paging on angular side  or When the user selects on next page fetch a response from spring rest and dispaly it on screen (connecting to db for every next page click).How can i implement sorting along with this .I have went through various examples and cant come to a solution. could somebody guide me the best practices on doing things. A snippet may be  where i can learn it myselves

Comment: Definitely go with paging from the server side. Angular js runs in the browser, this means that you would load all your data into the browser and then sort/page it. Not very good for performance especially when your data grows. One possible good implementation would be to only keep track of the page and page size on the angular side and then send these parameters to your rest service and retrieve the data as you go along. Definitely fetch the next page each time from your rest service.

Comment: Thanks prinay.where can i see some examples of those things. I'm searching and couldnt find any good resource.